# dual boot windows 8 eufi and Ubuntu on separate hard drives

Tags: windows-8

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed and working fine, added a second hard drive and installed windows 8 on the second hard drive. now windows works fine but only if I have the Ubuntu drive disconnected. Ubuntu will not boot at all anymore even with the windows drive disconnected. how can I get both systems to boot (dual Boot). again right now it only works if I disconnect the Ubuntu drive.
thanks,
Steven Reeves

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into windows after installing Ubuntu, two hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751693/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-two-hard-drives)

Answer (score 0):

This little tool should help: [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home)

You can use it either from your Ubuntu disc, or via a dedicated rescue disc.

[image]

Comment: This is not a direct answer. Much better would be a step-by-step guide: I am also trying to dual boot with a preinstalled Win8 on one disk and Ubuntu on another, and Boot-Repair didn't achieve this end.