# Can't boot windows after ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.04

I re-installed Ubuntu 14.04, but after that I can not boot to my windows 8.1 installation. I repaired my grub but still can not boot windows. Here is my [boot repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23672583/).

Can anyone help me with how to add a new menuentry in my grub.d 40_custom file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751693/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-two-hard-drives)

Comment: you can try to manually boot windows from *startup menu* of your computer (not `GRUB` menu) *if* you can find some option like `run UEFI application` in it. Then browse and run `bootx64.efi`. Once you boot Windows successfully, It will repair the boot sector itself.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem of grub installation not detecting Windows is because of the fast shutdown/resume feature. This stops grub from being able to mount the windows partition to verify that an install is there when it updates. If you reinstall the Windows bootloader, boot windows normally and shut down normally after disabling the feature, and reinstall grub, things should work fine.